# Skipping npm_install for a workspace with a cache in 2023

Tags: node.js, npm, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud

Let's say you have a monorepo with a module federation, with 5 different apps that you want to build in separate CI steps and you need to have all node_modules prior to executing the build of each app. With npm ci taking ~1min, that is 5 additional minutes for the whole CI, even with `--prefer-offline` and an .npm cache... It seems the main time-consumers of the installation are the dependency-checks with package-lock and not the download-times, the .npm-cache is really not making much of a difference, maybe just 15 seconds.

Instead of caching `$HOME/.npm`, I am trying to cache the ready-to-use node_modules folder. In a monorepo, you need to cache the non-hoisted node_modules in the workspaces too, but you can get a reference to them via `npm query .workspace | jq -r '.[].location'`, zip them all together and upon unpacking the cache, just put everything back into the respective subfolders/workspaces.

Now my problem is, you also need to link the workspaces in node-modules, e.g `node_modules/@my-company/some-lib`. `npm ci` does that automatically, but it also checks/installs external dependencies. Is there any way around this, to make npm only do the linking?

Are there any other things which would make this unstable? Keep in mind I already take care of versioning. I don't use package-lock.json for invalidating the cache but rather a package-lock.json-checksum without workspace-versions, so only externally installed packages matter.

Has anyone else tried this approach?

Comment: just fyi, it seems NX has a way of doing the linking in a monorepo instead of relying on a package-manager. See the package.json in the example without any workspace-definitions: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-recipes/blob/main. I will try their integrated repo approach